# Serializing python object to Json

Tags: python

I am struggling with serializing class to json file.

I tried two methodes, one to create directory, second to use jsons.

```
authorized_user = Login('1','test', 'test2')
vars(authorized_user)
jsons.dumps(authorized_user)
```

They both returned me:

```
{'_Login__request_type': '1', '_Login__username': 'test', '_Login__password': 'test2'}
```

How do I get rid of *Login* prefix?

What is more I would like to ask if there is a way to serialize object to json with more json naming convention. Like writing python class fields in python naming convention: __username, but parser would know that it is username.

Comment: you could rebuild the dict removing class name: `{k.split("__")[1]:v for k,v in vars(authorised_user)}`

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that your Login class is using double-underscore prefixes for its attributes, which invokes name mangling. This is almost never what you want to do anyway. But in order to help you further you need to show the code for that class.

Answer (score 2):

To modify the way your class is encoded into JSON format/get rid of *Login* prefix, you could use one of two different parameters for `json.dumps()`:

1. **Extending JSONEncoder (recommended)**

> To use a custom `JSONEncoder` subclass (e.g. one that overrides the
> `default()` method to serialize additional types), specify it with the
> *cls* kwarg; otherwise `JSONEncoder` is used.

```
class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Login):
            return {"request_type": obj.request_type, "username": obj.username, "password": obj.password}

json.dumps(authorized_user, cls=ComplexEncoder)
# {"request_type": "1", "username": "test", "password": "test2"}
```

2. **default param**

> If specified, *default* should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON encodable version of the object or raise a `TypeError`. If not specified, `TypeError` is raised.

```
def new_encoder(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Login):
        return {"request_type": obj.request_type, "username": obj.username, "password": obj.password}

json.dumps(authorized_user, default=new_encoder)
# {"request_type": "1", "username": "test", "password": "test2"}
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html